# Problem connecting socket.io to a physical device

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, socket.io

How can I connect two apps with socket.io . I create a server and the apps connect to the server but only in emulator, when I generate the apk and test it they don't connect. I don't get any error, I don't know what it can be.

////////////Server/////////////////

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const http = require('http')

const server = http.createServer(app);

const logger = require('morgan');

const cors = require('cors');

const { Server } = require('socket.io')

const io = new Server(server)

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const ordersSockets = require('./sockets/orderSocket');


app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());

ordersSockets(io)

server.listen(port, () => {

    console.log('application starting ' + process.pid)
})
```

////////////orderSocket////////////

```
module.exports = (io) => {

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {

        console.log('Client Connect')

        socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {

            console.log('disconnect')

        })


        socket.on('message', (message) => {

            console.log(message)

        })
    })

}
```

code in React Navite

```
 const Test = () => {

    socket.emit('message', message)

  }
  useEffect(() => {

    socket.connect();

    console.log('----------Connect----------------')

  }, []);
```

//////////utils///////

```
import  io  from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://ipofmycomputer:3000");

export default socket;
```

Comment: Are they in the same network?

Comment: Could you please include the error message?

Comment: So it is hard to tell but my money is `const server = http.createServer(app);` will create a server on 127.0.0.1 and so when your clients are trying to connect to `ipofmycomputer` from simulator it is found due to how simulator networking is done; and when you deploy them to device there is nothing actually listening on your IP, only on loopback. Or, of course, the firewall blocks port 3000 on your WiFi network...

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, this application you've developed is only configured to run on localhost.

If you just need to test whether your Android APK is able to connect to it, you can use ngrok to create a secure HTTPS tunnel which will redirect to your app running on localhost port `3000`

You will need to install ngrok, ensure that the app is running and then in command prompt / terminal enter:

`ngrok http 3000`

It will create a tunnel with a https link which you can specify inside your android app.

And last but not the least, make sure your socket.io server also has cors configured with options.

Your eventual aim should be to host your server on say Heroku or other alternatives, in which case you'll just need to configure your APK to connect to the hsoted instance.